# Flutter : stack widget one element after another without going under the first one

Tags: flutter

i'm creating messaging app but in the conversation screen last 2/3 messages are going under the message textfield.(where you write the message).
i'm using stack to show messages and and the textfield.

my code :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.toUser,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            )),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          
          children: [
          Container(
            child:chatMessageList()  ,
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 212, 192, 110),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                    controller: this._messageController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Message...",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        border: InputBorder.none),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  )),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      sendMessgae();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 156, 135, 47),
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 212, 192, 110)
                            ]),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.send,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 35.0,
                        )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[showing what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVRf5.png)

thanks for any help. I put the image only to explain my self.

Comment: You don't need `Stack` then, use `Column` insteaf

Comment: but when i click on textfield does it go up with keyboard? ps. doen't work

Comment: what "doesn't work"?

Comment: with column , it doesn't show up anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloumn like @pskink recommended in comments

Check that you wrap it with Padding ( padding : EdgeInsets.only(top : 5 ) ,child : Cloumn ... )

Comment: can you give me a code snippet , cause i can't get it to work with column